# How to return first async task to complete

Tags: elixir

I've got several tasks that I'm running asynchronously.  Depending on the input, one or more might run long, but only one of the tasks will return the :success message.

```
slowtask = Task.async(slow())
fasttask = Task.async(fast())
```

How can I capture the first of the two tasks above to complete, without having to wait for the other? I've tried `Task.find/2`, but because its implemented with enum, it seems to wait for all exit signals before finding a ref/message. My other thought was to poll this in `Stream.cycle`, ignoring still alive tasks and catching one that has exited.  It seems un elixir like to poll in this way though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this on Elixir yet. Your best option is, if you are only waiting for those messages in a given process, is something like this:

```
  defmodule TaskFinder do
    def run do
      task1 = Task.async fn -> :timer.sleep(1000); 1 end
      task2 = Task.async fn -> :timer.sleep(5000); 2 end
      await [task1, task2]
    end

    # Be careful, this will receive all messages sent
    # to this process. It will return the first task
    # reply and the list of tasks that came second.
    def await(tasks) do
      receive do
        message ->
          case Task.find(tasks, message) do
            {reply, task} ->
              {reply, List.delete(tasks, task)}
            nil ->
              await(tasks)
          end
      end
    end
  end

  IO.inspect TaskFinder.run
```

Note you could also use this pattern to spawn tasks in a GenServer and use `Task.find/2` to find the matching ones. I have also added this example to Elixir docs.

Comment: This got me on the right track to the answer below, which takes an expected message and returns that message from the first function that returns it.

Comment: Won't this lead to unflushed message of task2 and possibility of overflow?

Comment: As all of the answers rely on deprecated `Task.find` is there any idea how to do that without it?

Answer (score 3):

To get the first result, you should wait for a message, then pass the message to `Task.find/2`, and handle the first result which is in form of `{task_result, task}`.

```
defmodule Tasks do
  def run do
    :random.seed(:os.timestamp)
    durations = Enum.shuffle(1..10)

    Enum.map(durations, fn(duration) -> Task.async(fn -> run_task(duration) end) end)
    |> get_first_result
    |> IO.inspect
  end

  defp get_first_result(tasks) do
    receive do
      msg ->
        case Task.find(tasks, msg) do
          {result, _task} ->
            # got the result
            result

          nil -> 
            # no result -> continue waiting
            get_first_result(tasks)
        end
    end
  end


  defp run_task(1) do
    :success
  end

  defp run_task(duration) do
    :timer.sleep(duration * 100)
    :ok
  end
end
```

If the "master" process is a `GenServer` you should call `Task.find/2` from within `handle_info/2`, rather than running this recursive loop.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Jose Valim's answer, here's what I used to match the reply coming back:

```
def run do
    task1 = Task.async(fn -> :timer.sleep(10000); :slow end)
    task2 = Task.async(fn -> :timer.sleep(2000); :fail end)
    task3 = Task.async(fn -> :timer.sleep(1000); :fail end)

    await([task1, task2, task3])
end

def await(tasks) do
  receive do
    message ->
      case Task.find(tasks, message) do
        {:fail, task} ->
          await(List.delete(tasks, task))
        {reply, _task} ->
          reply             
        nil ->
          await(tasks)
      end
  end
end
```

This allowed me to match the first function to return something other than the :fail atom, and give me that reply.  Does this work because receive/1 just waits for any message to come along?

Comment: Yes, precisely. This looks like a great solution.

Comment: I can't think of a reasonable use case for something like this in a real application, but it is sure fun to brute force programming challenges by trying the problem every which way simultaneously!